# Issue with Table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a quick question about using the table command in mathematica. Suppose that I define

```
testpoints2 = 
 Table[{-6.510955872971275*^12 + 1.5*^11 (0.16639748772097088/(-1 + E^(
        1.0455062499999999` λ)) + 0.18909198788748088/(-1 + E^(1.1881000000000002 λ)) + 
       0.2301390424292751/(-1 + E^(1.4460062500000006 λ))), λ}, 
       {λ, 10^-8, 10^-2, 200}]
```

but it generates only one pair of values in the table (first entry)

```
{{7.16197*10^18, 1/100000000}}
```

Any suggestion why the other values are suppressed/not generated in the table. I first thought that mathematica does not show all the values in the table but listplotting the above table also shows only one point in the plot. Any suggestion about how to generate the whole set of points in the table will be much appreciated.

Comment: The `200` in there should be the increment, not the number of points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have next in your code:

```
{λ, 10^-8, 10^-2, 200}
```

In the documentation ([`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)) this is clearly stated that:

```
{i, i_min, i_max, di}
```

So, you try to have `di` much larger than the difference between `i_max` and `i_min`. Therefore it generates only one pair.